# Including Boost in VS Code on Mac (file not found)

Tags: c++, boost

I am running into an error while compiling this file (hello.cc):

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
int main() {
    return 0;
}
```

After executing: `g++ -o hello.o hello.cc`.
I am seeing: `fatal error: 'boost/asio.hpp' file not found`.

... even though I (edit: *thought* I) installed boost using brew at location: `/opt/homebrew/Cellar/boost/1.81.0_1` (edit: but it turns out it can better be considered to be installed at `/opt/homebrew/Cellar/boost/1.81.0_1/include`)

... and added `/opt/homebrew/Cellar/boost/1.81.0_1` to the `C_Cpp > Default: Include Path` Visual Studio Code setting

Compiling with `g++ -o hello.o -I /opt/homebrew/Cellar/boost/1.81.0_1 hello.cc` yields the same results.

How do I fix this?

Edit: Resolved. See solution below.

Answer (score 0):

For posterity: I fixed the problem by compiling with `g++ -o hello.o -I /opt/homebrew/Cellar/boost/1.81.0_1/include hello.cc`

This makes sense, because `boost/asio.hpp` is found in `/opt/homebrew/Cellar/boost/1.81.0_1/include`.